# Relations of variables in the 'for loop'

Tags: c++

Please consider the following code:

```
int col=0;
for(int l=0; rx_state_== MAC_COLL; l++)
{
col = col+1; // or col++;
}
return col;
```

My objective or logic for the above code is that, after for each instance of 'l', the rx_state == MAC_COLL must be checked and if true, the line 'col++' should be executed. (Sorry, I think I am explaining the basics of 'for loop' to experts) In the end, I require the total number of collisions (col) to be returned.

Now, my area of concern is that the integer 'l' has no particular connection with the variables involved in 'rx_state_ == MAC_COLL'; I just want the statement 'rx_state == MAC_COLL' to be checked continiously till its false and the number to be returned.

Will my objective be met with the above code?

Thanks

Comment: Is `rx_state` modified in another thread or signal handler? Otherwise it has no chance of changing and the loop (if entered) will never be left.

Comment: On the face of it, the condition `rx_state_ == MAC_COLL` will either be true on the first iteration and on all subsequent iterations and the loop won't stop unless the compiler decides it is undefined behaviour to keep on messing with `l` and `col` so that they overflow, or it will be false on the first iteration in which case `col` will be 0.

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If yes please check one so this topic can be considered closed, if not please provide some feedback or an answer of your own.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop can be translated to a `while` loop, something like:

```
int l=0; 
while (rx_state_ == MAC_COLL) { 
    col = col+1;
    l++;
}
return col;
```

Since you're apparently not really using `l`, it's probably simpler to code it as an actual `while` loop:

```
int col = 0;
while (rx_state_ == MAC_COLL)
    ++col;
return col;
```

...or you could code it as a `for` loop that does what you really seem to want:

```
for (int col=0; rx_state == MAC_COLL; ++col)
    ;
return col;
```

For any of these to make sense, either `rx_state` or `MAC_COLL` had better at least be qualified as `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop would probably be better here:

```
while (rx_state_== MAC_COLL)
    col++;
```

However, you should think about *how* `rx_state` will be changed if you just loop without having any other code that may do the change a chance to run. And if you're using threads then there are better ways than to busy-wait (which may use a *lot* of CPU power for doing basically nothing). If you *must* busy wait, then I suggest you throw in a short delay in the loop, to let the CPU do other things except your loop.

Answer (score 0):

It will. But what you are doing is basically a while.

```
int col=0;
while(rx_state_== MAC_COLL)
{
    col = col+1; // or col++;
}
return col;
```